# How to fire an event React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I have some code, in a hook, to detect whether the browser is online / offline:

```
export function useConnectivity() {
  const [isOnline, setNetwork] = useState(window.navigator.onLine);
  const updateNetwork = () => {
    setNetwork(window.navigator.onLine);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('offline', updateNetwork);
    window.addEventListener('online', updateNetwork);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('offline', updateNetwork);
      window.removeEventListener('online', updateNetwork);
    };
  });
  return isOnline;
}
```

I have this basic test:

```
test('hook should detect offline state', () => {
  let internetState = jest.spyOn(window.navigator, 'onLine', 'get');
  internetState.mockReturnValue(false);

  const { result } = renderHook(() => useConnectivity());
  expect(result.current.valueOf()).toBe(false);
});
```

However, I want to run a test to see whether it returns the correct value when an `offline` event is triggered, not just after the mocking of the returned value on render. What is the best way to approach this? Where I have got so far is this:

```
test('hook should detect offline state then online state', async () => {
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useConnectivity());

  act(() => {
    const goOffline = new window.Event('offline');
    window.dispatchEvent(goOffline);
  });

  await waitForNextUpdate();
  
  expect(result.current).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure about 'best', but this is one way: change the mock response halfway through the test, and tweak some of the async code:

```js
test('hook should detect online state then offline state', async () => {
  const onLineSpy = jest.spyOn(window.navigator, 'onLine', 'get');

  // Pretend we're initially online:
  onLineSpy.mockReturnValue(true);

  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useConnectivity());

  await act(async () => {
    const goOffline = new window.Event('offline');

    // Pretend we're offline:
    onLineSpy.mockReturnValue(false);

    window.dispatchEvent(goOffline);

    await waitForNextUpdate();
  });

  expect(result.current).toBe(false);
});
```